# Load class according to string

Tags: java

I'm quite new in Java and need some help implementing the following:

In a mongodb-instance I save follwing data-structure:

```
{
    name: String,
    type: String // or anything else that might make this task easier
    data [Array of objects]
}
```

The data structure of the `data` field depends of the `type` of the document.
The `type` also declares a certain Class, that handles populating and parsing the `data`.

My idea of accomplishing something like this with my current knowlegde would be to have a `HashMap<String, Class>` and then registering the type and the appropriate class.

Another way (which I don't know yet how to implement) would be to store the excat classname as the `type` and then trying to cast this string to a Class, but since the HashMap-way would probably be easier I thought I'd rather try this way.

What would be a good approach solving this problem?

Comment: Your idea sounds good to me. I wouldn't store the exact class name in the database. You'll probably change the class names and locations frquently, or even switch to a different language to implement your app, and you don't want to change everything in your database every time you do that. Store a logical type, not a concrete Java type. Data survives code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)